# Using and posting input in Laravel sweetalert

Tags: javascript, laravel, sweetalert

I am using sweetalert in my Laravel project. I want a number to be entered in the input. I want to get which button is clicked and the value in the input when it is clicked. But when I click the confirm button, I can only get the value. How can I fix this?

```js
function test() {
          swal({
                     title: "Example Title",
  text: "Example description",
   content: "input",
  showCancelButton: true,
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  icon: "info",
    buttons: {
    cancel: "Second Button",
    confirm: "First Button",
  },
  inputPlaceholder: "Write something"
                  }).then(function(isConfirm,inputValue) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                      swal("Thank You !", "Input:  "+isConfirm);
                    }
                    else {
                      swal("Thank you !", "Input: "+isConfirm+" We hope you come again.");
                    }
                                    });  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="test" class="btn btn-success" onclick="test()" >Test</button>
```

When I click the first button everything works. But when I click the second button, I cannot get the value. How can I get the value when the 2nd button is also clicked?

Note: I need to know which button was clicked. I operate according to the button.

Additionally, the input must be a number. It should not accept any value other than a number.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37nk0beq/)

Answer (score 0):

For only numbers you can use  `input: 'number',`

And here for detect which button clicked:

```
if (isConfirm) {
   swal("Clicked Confirm Button");
 }
 else {
   swal("Clicked Cancel Button");
}
```

Comment: I was using this before. But when I click the Cancel button, I cannot get the value entered in the input.